# Prevent loading of entire CSS stylesheet - only load needed content?

Tags: html, css, caching, page-load-time

I'm trying to improve my site speed as I integrate certain features of a theme I purchased into my site and came across this interesting feature on the website of said theme.

The problem I have now is my CSS style sheet is absolutely massive (220kb) and takes ages (3-4 seconds) to load. I'm working to reduce that, but that's a different story...

When I try to load that exact same page on the theme dev's website, it loads much faster. Upon inspection, on my website, I find my  'Size' and 'Content' amounts of the stylesheet in the dev tools is about identical.

On the developer's page, the size is much smaller than the content. Does this mean that ONLY the elements called upon in the HTML are downloaded from the stylesheet? If yes, how does one accomplish this, because it sounds tremendously efficient.

I also thought it was because the dev's page was caching the content on my browser but I've disabled cache and it still only loads a portion of the content.

My website's cache works by the way, I'm just interested in speeding up that initial load time.

Any thoughts?

Relevant imagery:

Cache Disabled:

Dev's website with small size/content ratio - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdFO4.png

My website with ~1:1 size/content ratio - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvwvk.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Off the top of my head, you could minify your CSS. There's a few free tools around including the Page Speed Insights for Chrome.

See https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/MinifyResources

It looks like your CSS is already in a minified file, but perhaps the content isn't!

---

Just so people aren't confused. The solution was to enable gzip on the server, which you can read more about at https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/gzip (but still minify your css as well).

Comment: Holy F### I just enabled GZip thanks to that article.
This is how I feel:
http://stream1.gifsoup.com/webroot/animatedgifs2/1365838_o.gif

Thank you for the excellent post

Comment: My pleasure. GZip for the win!

Comment: One quick question on GZip - this is 100% on my server, correct? So support for a GZipped version of the files is not necessary on the part of the client? It doesn't matter if he's accessing the site with an outdated browser/computer/configuration, he will receive the compressed version no matter what, right? (Assuming my site can be run on outdated browsers/os without issue.)

Comment: Yes (mostly), the browser identifies as having gzip support and if the server has gzip enabled then it sends a gzipped page, otherwise it will send a normally served page. See this > https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/gzip

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to user worldofjr, I found the answer to be ENABLE GZIP on the server.

Unbelievable increase in speed.

That should be required reading whenever someone signs up for webhosting. I can't believe my site has gone 1 year without this when it took 2 seconds to enable!!!

Answer (score 1):

"On the developer's page, the size is much smaller than the content. Does this mean that ONLY the elements called upon in the HTML are downloaded from the stylesheet? If yes, how does one accomplish this, because it sounds tremendously efficient."

That's not generally how css works. And what you describe might not be very efficient even if you did somehow implement it. The server would have to know which styles to send, which would require the browser to load the page and send in it's list and the server would have to generate the custom css and send it back...

You certainly can limit which css loads where--and you should. But that has to be done manually, at least in my experience.

Anyway, a few things to consider before you proceed:

I think 200k is really, really big for a stylesheet. Most sites I work on the total CSS weight might be 20k. Or less. I'd investigate why yours is so huge. Maybe something has gone wrong. Minifying might help, but it isn't going to knock you down a whole order of magnitude.

However, even if it is the world's largest CSS file, 200k isn't THAT big. Not 4-5 seconds big. I'm working on a site right now where an entire page weighs ~350kb and I have it loading in under a second. Again, I suspect something else has gone wrong. The size of that CSS is probably indicative of *something* but I suspect it's not purely the time it takes the file to download.

Comment: The reason that global.css file is so massive is because this is a theme I'm working on. So they have every possible permutation for every element on there and the naming scheme is terrible (E.g. xx-section-borders-has-borders-green-outline then down a list of 20 variations for different colors etc). I've been selectively pulling the items I need out of there and integrating them into a smaller global file for my specific site. My current file is about 63KB before any compression. And that's before my typography files and specific plugin stylesheets...